Is there a reason SpaceX does not spiral weld Starship rocket bodies?
Spiral welding is a standard manufacturing technique for forming tubular metal structures.

Being a continuous process, spiral welding is ideal for automated welders. Quality control and re-welding are also incorporated into the continuous process.
Spiral welding can produce sections of optimum length, not just rings which happen to be the same axial length as the material roll. Current Starship ring width was not chosen to optimize design. Ring width was limited to the maximum roll width available from steel mills.
Spiral welding can reduce total weld length. The total weld length is equal to the perimeter of the roll. Any other design strategy which involves cutting the roll (like rings) increases the perimeter and therefor increases weld length.
Spiral welding eliminates the vulnerable "skelp weld" which closes the ring sections. In a pressurized cylinder, wall tension is greater circumferentially than axially. This maximum tension is carried by the skelp weld. Spiral welding eliminates the skelp weld. If this is the most vulnerable location in the ring, spiral welding could potentially reduce material thickness and rocket mass.
Because spiral welding can occur on a horizontal surface (as opposed to vertical assembly of rings), Submerged Arc Welding techniques can be used. This technique can be up to 10X faster than the Gas Shielded Metal Arc welding used by SpaceX on its vertical welds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submerged_arc_weldingm. Spiral welding would also be an ideal application for Friction Stir welding.
This technique would seem to have advantages for mass production of rocket bodies.

https://www.techtimes.com/articles/288269/20230227/worlds-first-spiral-welded-wind-turbine-tower-now-up-running.htm
According to Elon's "Idiot Index" Is Elon’s “Idiot Index” an over-simplification? , his mantra is:
1) Question: why are tubular rockets not manufactured using the technique which has been the industry standard for fabricating tubes for over half a century?
2) Delete: get rid of the axial "skelp weld" in every ring section
3) Simplify: go to a continuous, rather than batch process
4) Accelerate: submerged arc welding is many times faster than gas shielded arc welding
5) Automate: an automated spiral weld process (like that used for making thousands of miles of pipeline) would allow automation of the entire process including post weld inspection, corrective welding, and cut-off into pre-selected optimum lengths
Elon has envisioned mass production of thousands of starships. This would justify an on-site rolling mill to produce continuous sheets (optimum width, no rolls, no skelps) feeding into a continuous spiral welder. The flying cut-off would produce sections of lengths that were optimized to suit the component they were intended for.
This proposed on-site rolling process could vary material thickness as desired, producing variable wall thickness including tapering thickness. Varying the sheet width could produce tapered sections including transitions between cylinders of different diameters and "bullet" noses.

Well, that article is from 2023, so the tech may be newer than the development of the current launch hardware. Perhaps next generation?

The asymmetry that results from this might be an issue too?

Guessing as a comment rather than an answer:  the rings are more-suitable to rocket construction because a ring can have the dome for a tank installed, and the tank body can be more rings, etc etc.  So the rocket doesn't need the looooooooooooong continuous of a wind turbine tower; it needs stuff inside it.

I think the asymmetrical spiral is very significant in such a weight sensitive structure. Not only is the weld a spiral but so is the rolled metal's grain structure. As rolling of the raw metal from bulk ingot to thinner and thinner stock that then gets trimmed and rolled on to the delivered coil... the individual grain structures within metal get longer and longer and longer... resulting in a 'directionality' of the metal and its properties.

Also a guess: the whole Starship development process very much follows the philosophy of "get something working, then iterate." Remember that Starhopper was built by water tower workers. So an advanced technique like this would not have been used initially even if it is in principle better. I'm interested to see if anyone has actual knowledge about whether it is in principle suited for this use.

@ErinAnne ... Section length is determined by choosing the cut-off point (as opposed to roll width) so sections can be whatever length is most suitable for the rocket design.

@Woody sure, but if it's already easy to make rings of the size you want/need out of delivered steel stock sizes, you do that instead of making a continuous welding rig. Maybe. I think Charles Staats' point is also quite right--there might be no particular reason not to other than that they started in a tent and haven't so far, and maybe at a production cadence it would be suitable.  Interesting question, upvoting

@BradV ... anisotropy can be controlled by annealing and the rolling processes. Untreated rolled sheet 304 can have a tensile strength anisotropy of 5-15%. Reducing this anisotropy with annealing should reduce the anisotropy further, which could be engineered into the design.

@BradV ... the circumference of Starship is 28 meters and the width of the SS sheet rolls is 1.8 meters. So the angle of the spiral welded sheet would be only 3.6* from the horizontal. This should have a trivial effect on circumferential tensile strength due to anisotropy .

The structure shown in Why does the YF-75D nozzle have such a strong spiral pattern? and those referenced in its answer(s) is certainly not the kind of spiral welding you're probably asking about, but topologically it might be at least congruent. (tongue loosely planted in cheek)

well dangit @woody... I wish you'd stop making reasonable points!.  ;)

@BradV ... my daughter could reassure you that I am much more often unreasonable.

Is the thickness of the Starship skin uniform? Or do they use a thinner gauge sheet at the top?

@Slarty it's a good question... engines push mostly axially (except when they don't), stiffness against flexure and strength against flexure failure should be in the middle, and of course at Max-Q compression is maximum uniformly along the length. And when it's mostly dry it's got to hang by the grid fins in tension with the maximum at the grid fins.

@Slarty ... Wikipedia says the SS skin is a uniform 0.16" thickness, but Chat GPT claims otherwise (without references, of course).

@JonCuster ... spiral welding was developed in Germany in the 1930's so we're coming up on a century of experience with it.

@Woody We do not trust what ChatGPT says. Period.

They currently add internal stringers for stiffness and baffles for fuel slosh, which I assume are installed in between ring section welds. Installing those pieces in between spiral welds would seem to be more complex in terms of predicting their performance. Or I guess the pieces could span the weld joints, although that means each piece has to have a custom cutout, adding a little more complexity to the build. But maybe it wouldn't be that hard.

there's that coil width question, to some extent one might want to get rid of the coil and minimize pitch, by building the tube out of additive welding spiraling along tube's axis.

@user721108 ... SpaceX said they used the 72' wide coils because that was the widest standard size currently available. If SpaceX fills Elon's stated goal of building thousands of starships, it would justify building a mill that would produce the optimum width. Perhaps even an integrated mill/starship production line using continuous sheet production with no "rolls" and therefor no skelp welds (only the spirals)

Related discussion on NSF and their conclusions: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=49142.0  - based on just outsider guesses, but has some interesting thoughts. There is a tweet by Elon Musk saying that they at least intend to vary the thickness from ring to ring.

I'll take a stab at this from an industrial engineering perspective because that's what I'm most familiar with:
Efficiency, Effectiveness, and Cycle Time
Basically, the idea of using spiral welding to make the body of the rocket has similar vibes to 3d printing buildings: it is very cool in theory or even in a prototype, but in the end it is mostly pointless because you are fundamentally optimizing the wrong thing (efficient but ineffective).
When you're constructing residential houses, putting up the walls and framing is basically the fastest and easiest step (the Amish famously build a barn in a day). What takes time is doing all the "fiddly bits" like HVAC, electrical, etc. Now, if you have your building 3d-printer, you are spending a lot of money on a highly complex machine that... doesn't really have any advantages. Yes, it theoretically it might save time, but from a cycle time perspective, that doesn't matter because there are other work steps that are the bottleneck.
In industrial engineering this cycle time is often shown with a chart like this one:
 (click for source)
Here, the different sequential manufacturing process steps are shown on the bottom (A, B, C, ...) and the time it takes to complete each manufacturing step before it is handed on to the step is shown by the cycle time (CT, usually in seconds, minutes, or hours).
On this chart you can draw a horizontal line (such as "Takt time" in the chart) and if all the process times are below this line, you have a (theoretically) functional assembly line. Helpfully, the image also has a bottleneck illustrated. This is a process step that takes so long, that essentially all other steps in the chain are waiting on it to complete, and thus it determines the pace at which the product can be manufactured.
In this example, switching to continuous spiral welding would be like lowering the time it takes to complete process C. Welding is very likely not a bottlneck that the whole Starship production line is waiting on, and since engineers only have a limited amount of work hours they can spend on optimizing process, they should logically choose to invest their optimization effort in another step where gains will impact the entire production chain.
Simultaneous manufacturing
Another point is that assembly through attaching rings has advantages for parallelizing manufacturing: If you have a bunch of ring sections, workers can do work on these sections simultaneously and then combine them later. Starting out with one long tube might be practical in one way, but then they need to install a bunch of electronics, plumbing, valves, etc and you can only have so many people working on one thing at a time.
If you break it up into ring sections, not only can people work on it indoors at reasonable heights and angles, but you also have a modular system where you can have some manufacturing sub-chain entirely focused on cranking out "ring section 18" or whatever and then you end up with a universal part that can be combined into any stack or swapped out before being welded on.
Eventually though?
Of course, there does come a point where welding of the rocket body will become a bottleneck if you are trying to push manufacturing truly into the mass-manufacturing scale. Like, if you're cranking out >10 rockets per workday and you need tube sections as fast as possible. Then, it might be worth investigating if creating the body tube in this way can shave a couple work hours off of the production process.
Doubt this will be soon though.

Re last point I'd suggest the key break point is if your spiral welding rig has the additional hardware to weld in tank dividers and plumbing fixtures while the spiral weld runs, getting you mostly complete rockets 'extruded' but at the cost of much more complex hardware up front (needs multiple welding heads working spiral and cylindrical simultaneously, and holding/rotating the additional parts as they are welded in)

You could probably put up a wood framed house in a day, but there's no way your putting up entire brick walls in one day, especially not cement blocks as used in Europe.
You've also kind of missed the point of 3d printed houses, they require less people. In places like Ireland, labor is a big part of why they're in a housing crisis because so many people emigrated or didn't take up trades.
I'd much rather pay for a fancy printer for a couple days than deal with the headache's that come with traditional construction.

@ChellCPlus You're right that bricklaying is slower than wooden framing, but even in a cinder-block construction, a team of 3-5 skilled bricklayers should be able to do the bricklaying within a workweek week for a normal house. If you pay 4 bricklayers 250 EUR a day and they get the job done in 5 days, then that's 5k + materials, and I don't think you'll be able to make an economical robot that can do everything skilled humans can do for under 5k anytime soon. The much better option is pre-fab components, where you can benefit from mass manufacturing modules and then installing them on-site.

I'd assume you'd rent the robot, so you wouldn't be paying 5k presumably, just the cost of the operator and rental cost for the machine. The robots I've seen so far seem to be a good bit faster than bricklaying as well. You'd be lucky to get skilled bricklayers for 250 euro a day nowadays. Pre-fab is an excellent idea but very hit or miss depending on the company you go with. I've seen pre-fabs 20 years old and still look new, and others that have leaking roofs after a couple years of use.

It may be that it is just easier to manufacture a number of sub assemblies and fit them with bulkheads, thrust structures, domes, flap fittings, access ports, stringers, heat shield mounting points, header tanks, COPV's, cold thrusters etc individually while they are in small pieces and can be turned upside down if required for easier processing rather than try to do it all on some large enclosed monolithic structure.
It might also be easier to make changes. A change to the dome design could mean just scraping one section rather than the whole ship.

I can think of a few reasons:

A spiral welding jig large enough to fabricate a Superheavy booster would be enormous and expensive, and it would lock in aspects of the construction: it would give an upper bound to the length and diameter of the booster, for instance.
SpaceX is still at the prototyping stage, which benefits from having a more flexible assembly process.

When you use spiral welding, you end up with an empty tube 71 meters long, which would have to be fitted with its contents from the inside, unless you make the jig even more elaborate to allow fitting internals to the section being currently welded together (place a tank bulkhead and wrap the skin around it). That long tube also has no structural strength yet, and would deform under its own weight, so you have to build another giant jig to support the tube while it's being outfitted.



A spiral welding  jig does not put bounds on diameter or length. Length is endless. The cuts-offs produces desired lengths. You could even cut-off into 6' rings (same as current rings) but why would you want to? Or the cut-off could be located at the bulkheads.

"Enormous and expensive". Sounds like Starship.

A spiral welding jig has to support the tube that comes out of it, especially if you're forming a 9-meter diameter tube out of very thin steel.

How do you know that you've completed the correct length of spiral?  What if it's 2cm longer, or shorter?  Or if the temperature has varied between this morning and this afternoon, and so the metal has shrunk or expanded or...
Where was with rings, it's very clear you've finished - you can count them easily.  And welds on a single ring section are going to be always at a fairly consistent temperature.
What if it matters if a fitting goes in at a specific spot in the spiral?  How will that complicate things?  Rings are really easy to plan around.
Spirals... there's a reason we talk about spiraling into depression!
